# Why can't message be delivered to Akka actor?

Tags: akka

I have one actor sending a message to another actor. It successfully does so multiple times, but after a few messages, the second actor stops processing the messages. The system itself isn't very loaded.

The test that reproduces the problem is:

```
test("case2: Primary (in isolation) should react properly to Insert, Remove, Get") {
  val arbiter = TestProbe()

  val primary = system.actorOf(Replica.props(arbiter.ref, Persistence.props(flaky = false)), "case2-primary")
  val client = session(primary)

  arbiter.expectMsg(Join)
  arbiter.send(primary, JoinedPrimary)

  client.getAndVerify("k1")
  client.setAcked("k1", "v1")
  client.getAndVerify("k1")
  client.getAndVerify("k2")
  client.setAcked("k2", "v2") // assertion failure happens here
  client.getAndVerify("k2")
  client.removeAcked("k1")
  client.getAndVerify("k1")
}
```

Since this is part of a Coursera course, I'd rather not post my implementation.

What kinds of things might cause this failure?

Comment: Can you really getAndVerify a message several times? And will you see if that fail before trying to set something in the actor?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the same message type had been processed. For example, `setAcked("k1", "v1")` sends the message `Insert("k1", "v1", someId)` and `setAcked("k2", "v2")` sends the message `Insert("k2", "v2", someOtherId)`. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Well, it was just a long-shot. When using clojure agents (which resembles of actors, somewhat), an error is not seen directly, but when you try to use the result. If there was an error at getAndverify("k2"), would there be an asseration failure there? Can `k2` happen be `null` without any asseration failure at this row?

Comment: It turned out to be a bug on my part. I was in the middle of redesigning and had left a 'self forward message' which caused an 'infinite message loop'.